# Limited SQL query returns all rows instead of one

Tags: mysql, select, limit

I tried the SQL code:

```
explain SELECT * FROM myTable LIMIT 1
```

As a result I got:

```
id select_type table   type possible_keys key  key_len ref  **rows**
1  SIMPLE      myTable ALL  NULL          NULL NULL    NULL **32117**
```

Do you know why the query would run though all rows instead of simply picking the first row?
What can I change within the query (or in my table) to reduce the line amount for a similar result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rows count shown is only an *estimate* of the number of rows to examine. It is not always equal to the *actual* number of rows examined when you run the query.

In particular:

> LIMIT is not taken into account while estimating number of rows Even if you have LIMIT which restricts how many rows will be examined MySQL will still print full number.

[Source](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/24/mysql-explain-limits-and-errors/)

When the query actually runs only one row will be examined.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info.
did I get you well that I have the benefit of LIMIT but simply cant see that in explain here?
I bet this also aplies to the estimated runtime which is a bit higher than without the limit but far below 1second anway so I cannot say it from my own expirience here.

Comment: @PeterFrey: Yes, you get the correct performance that you would expect when using LIMIT, but you can't see it in the output of EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited for use of subselect:**

Assuming the primary key is "my_id" , use `WHERE`. For instance:

```
select * from mytable
where my_id = (
select max(my_id) from mytable
)
```

While this seems less efficient at first, the result is as such in explain, resulting in just one row returned and a read on the index to find max. I do not suggest doing this against partitioned tables in MySQL:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY mytable const   PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   const   1    
2   SUBQUERY    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Select tables optimized away
```

Comment: actually by doing max(my_id) you would actually have to go through every row to find the id that is the largest unless the field is indexed. which would actually be worse than it just returning just the 1st item as mark byers stated

Comment: actually, in this specific example this will result in the opposite, undesired behaviour. When there is no INDEX for `my_id` then this would force MySQL to examine all 32117 rows to find the maximum value. If `my_id` is the PRIMARY KEY, then there already is an INDEX on it, of course.

Comment: Edited to make the inane assumption that my_id is the primary key, therefore an indexed column. I incorrectly assumed this would be inferred.